# Test for existance of column in table Matlab

Tags: matlab, boolean, matlab-table

I Have the following table, T:

```
      Hold       Min    Max 
    _________    ___    ____

     0.039248    0      0.05
     0.041935    0      0.05
     0.012797    0      0.05
    0.0098958    0      0.05
     0.014655    0      0.05
```

How can I test if a column in a table exists? For example `isfield(T,'Hold')` returns `0`. `Exist`, `isstruct` also do not work. I would need the test to simply return a true or false result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert to `struct` and then use `isfield`:

```
isfield(table2struct(T),'Hold')
```

Comment: This might be a performance hit for larger data sets. Probably better to use [solution by excaza](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32656035/388664) (with Mohsen's comment).

Answer (score 5):

See: [Table Properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tableproperties.html)

For example:

```
LastName = {'Smith';'Johnson';'Williams';'Jones';'Brown'};
Age = [38;43;38;40;49];
Height = [71;69;64;67;64];
Weight = [176;163;131;133;119];
BloodPressure = [124 93; 109 77; 125 83; 117 75; 122 80];

T = table(Age,Height,Weight,BloodPressure,...
    'RowNames',LastName);

myquery = 'Age';
columnexists = ismember(myquery, T.Properties.VariableNames)
```

Returns:

```
columnexists =

     1
```

Comment: You can use `ismember` in last line `columnexists =ismember(myquery, T.Properties.VariableNames)`

Answer (score 0):

```
ismember('myFieldName', myTable.Properties.VariableNames)
```

or put into a nice function:

```
function hasField = tablehasfield(t, fieldName)
    hasField = ismember(fieldName, t.Properties.VariableNames);
end
```

How to use the function:

```
x = [2 5 3];
t = table(x); % create table with a field called 'x'

if tablehasfield(t, 'x')
    % do something
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual tests cause a script to crash if the subject (Table in this case) doesn't exist: `isfield(), ismember(), isempty()` these all have that problem.

`exist()` checks without crashing, but only works on the table, so you still need checks for the existence of the column, 
and you asked whether there was data in the column:

```
%define table
Hold = [0.039248 0.041935 0.012797 0.0098958 0.014655]';
Min=[0 0 0 0 0]';
Max = [0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05]';
T = table(Hold,Min,Max);

%test table
if exist('T') 
   myquery = 'Max';
   if ismember(myquery, T.Properties.VariableNames)
       col = find(strcmp(myquery, T.Properties.VariableNames));
       T(:,col)
   end
 end
```

...and displays it as a bonus